# email is sent but does not reach to mailbox using devise method "confirmable" for confirming user by email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I am implementing devise "confirmable" method to confirm user by sending email for ruby on rails App.
My app "development.log" file shows that email has been sent but it does not reach on destination. 
Following are my files containing code:-

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  attr_accessible :title, :body
  def password_match?
    self.errors[:password] << 'must be provided' if password.blank?
    self.errors[:password] << 'and confirmation do not match' if password != password_confirmation
    password == password_confirmation and !password.blank?
  end
end
```

confirmations_controller.rb

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_confirmation_token(params[:confirmation_token])
  end
ef confirm_user
    @user = User.find_by_confirmation_token(params[:user][:confirmation_token])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user]) and @user.password_match?
      @user = User.confirm_by_token(@user.confirmation_token)
      set_flash_message :notice, :confirmed
      sign_in_and_redirect("user", @user)
    else
      render :show
    end
  end
```

sign up page

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>



  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

development.rb

```
Gt::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {:address => "localhost", :port => 1025}

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
   :tls => true,
   :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
   :port => 587,
   :domain => "gmail.com",
   :authentication => :login,
   :user_name => "[username]",
   :password => "[password]"
 }

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true
end
```

log output

```
Sent mail to xy@gmail.com (2027ms)
Date: Wed, 27 Mar 2013 23:29:12 +0530
From: please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com
Reply-To: please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com
To: xy@gmail.com
Message-ID: <515333707f095_3501ae36c81486e@Vinay-PC.mail>
Subject: Confirmation instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Welcome xy@gmail.com!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>
```

Problem: email is sent as i can see from development log but it does not reach to given email id.I am on localhost.
Any help would be appriciated.

Regards,
Vieenay Siingh

Answer (score 1):

you need to set up a default host and mailer setting in config/application.rb file.

[image: email configuration for rails]

Comment: also make sure that you have config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true so that you come to know that what problem you are facing with the email sending.

Comment: hi maximus,thanks, but how to set host and mailer settings in config/application.rb file.I have already set parameter that you showed me above.

Comment: hi maximus, my email has been sent but never reached to mailbox or not even to spam.

Comment: Sorry I didn't got this in first look, you already mentioned this in your question.But have you tried setting  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors to true in development.rb, so that you get exception that arising due to some reasons like wrong email/password? As well do check sent box of configured email.

Comment: Hi maximus, now it is working. I think problem was with STMP settings.but now I am getting following error. [NameError in ConfirmationsController#confirm_user

undefined local variable or method `unconfirmed_email' for #<User:0x3f9e2f8>
Rails.root: d:/thursday/tuesday

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/confirmations_controller.rb:8:in `confirm_user'
Request
]
Parameters:

Comment: check if some where you are using unconfirmed_email or method in confirmation controller. application trace can help you in the context. You can always use debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem but got it solved by doing the following trick.

The solution is to create an initialiser in config/initialisers/setup_mail.rb containing the following

if Rails.env != 'test'
  email_settings = YAML::load(File.open("#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/email.yml"))
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = email_settings[Rails.env] unless email_settings[Rails.env].nil?
end

then add config/email.yml containing the details of the dev and production email accounts

development:
  :address: smtp.gmail.com
  :port: 587
  :authentication: plain
  :user_name: xxx
  :password: yyy

production:
  :address: smtp.gmail.com
  :port: 587
  :authentication: plain
  :user_name: xxx
  :password: yyy

Comment: Hi nilay,now it works fine.I think problem was with SMTP settings.But now i am getting "NameError in ConfirmationsController#confirm_user

undefined local variable or method `unconfirmed_email'" error, when I try to confirm user by providing password and confirm_password.